# How to change BMP (beats per minute) for an audio in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I have an audio file (mp3) which I have to play in different BMPs. I want some way to change the current BMP of the song and play at it.

There is a picker which lets user to pick BMP at which he wants the song to play:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the speed of audio player. Say you alreay know that BPM is 60 and now you want to play it at 90, you simply need to make the play speed 1.5 times faster by using the following code

```
let audioP = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: selectedPath), fileTypeHint: "caf")
audioP.enableRate = true
audioP.prepareToPlay()
audioP.rate = 1.5// Change your rate here
audioP.play()
```